# Align 2 objects edges side by side - Align multiple vertices to nearest edges automatically

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, edges, loop

Trying to :

- Align 2 objects edges side by side OR
- Align one set of edges from one object to another set of edges from another object OR
- Align multiple vertices to nearest edges automatically

I have two terrain tiles with a different subdivision level of details. What I want is to align all vertices of the most detailed tile to the edge of the less detailed tile.

[image]

1/ Do you have a practical way to do this?
I tried the addon LoopTools :
LoopTools > Gstretch > spread evenly
but the process is very manual and I need to fix many tiles.

2/ Is there a way to select many vertices to target multiple edges from another model.

align one loop to match another less detailed loop from two different objects :
[image]

Blend file link : https://github.com/onelsonic/blender/raw/main/next-tiles.blend

Thank you

Comment: I might try selecting all involved vertices, F, triangulate faces, smooth vertices.

Comment: > nope did not work when selecting both edges loops.

Comment: Hang on, these are loops? Try Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: bridge will bridge and not move the actual vertices also they are from two different models

Comment: You can collapse the new bridge edges after they’re created. Why do you mention that they’re from two different models?

Comment: what I want is just moving the vertices of on object to snap to the edges of another object, using bridge will create new vertices and collapse them, messing with other things like Uvs.

Comment: Hmm, try the snap modifier. It might have some settings to do what you want, possibly involving assigning the hem vertices to a group that it affects solely.